# Magento 2.3.4 cron job reindex error

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4, magento-cron

i've a problem with Magento Cron.
I activate magento cron by terminal command as wrote in Magento 2 User Guide.
But when i open log file i found this error

```
[2020-04-22 12:53:05] main.ERROR: Cron Job indexer_reindex_all_invalid has an error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '80728-152-1-5778-80728' for key$
[2020-04-22 12:53:05] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '80728-152-1-5778-80728' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT  INTO `avm_catalog_product_indez_eav_temp
```

how can i fix it?

Thanks

Antonello

Comment: run this  --- `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` after check

Comment: same error. I don't understand why i have this problem with reindex

Comment: solved https://firebearstudio.com/blog/magento-2-integrity-constraint-violation-issues-solutions.html